# Draw New Circle on Bitmap Android

Tags: android, geometry, draw, new-operator

I want to draw a circle on a canvas and have it leave a trail, rather draw a new circle each time.  How would I go about doing this?  All I can get it to do is move the circle around.

-CanvasTest Class

```
package canvas.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CanvastestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    float x = 80;
    float y = 20;
    float r = 15;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        Draw2D d = new Draw2D(this, x, y, r);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            x++;
            y++;
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        setContentView(d);
    }
}
```

--Draw2D Class

```
package canvas.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Draw2D extends View {  

float x;
float y;
float r;

public Draw2D(Context context, float x, float y, float r) {
    super(context);
    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);
    
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.drawPaint(paint);
    
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);   
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);     
    c.drawCircle(x, y, r, paint);
}
}
```

This is my most recent test.  Why would the circle now move?  It does not move at all.

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing something like canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) or canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK) in the begining of your doDraw method?

If you omit that call it should not clear the canvas and leave the trails you are looking for.

Comment: I am not using that.  What I am doing is drawing a blank white bitmap onto the canvas, and then trying to draw the circle there.

Comment: I am doing the drawing in onDraw, should I be drawing somewhere else?

Comment: if you posted some sample code it would be a little easier to see, but if you are drawing your white bitmap on every 'draw' call then that is erasing your circle.  You would either need to store all the locs for your circle and draw them all every request, or just paint the background the firstime, and then paint then new circle location on every call to paint.

Comment: `onDraw` is the right place to do that. Try `canvas.drawColor(0x88FFFFFF)` instead of your bitmap. that should be 50% transparent white and you get a nice fading trail effect.

Comment: 'canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1, 0, 0, null);'  This is inside onDraw and draws the white bitmap.  How do I get around this?

Comment: just draw it the first time you enter onDraw  for example  `onDraw{ if(firstTime){canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1,0,0,null); firstTime=false;}//rest of drawing code}`

Comment: I had something exactly like that. It will draw the white background once and then it doesn't exist anymore.  It goes black.  So, should I will try an idea I have and if it is successful I will post it.  If you guys have any more ideas I would appreciate the help.  Thanks.

Comment: and to get some animation you just need to create a new thread, and then call a method on your view to update x and y, you should then be able to call postinvalidate on the view to repaint it..